# error: duplicate class: android.support.v7.appcompat.R

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try to compile my project I get this error message `"Error:(9, 14) error: duplicate class: android.support.v7.appcompat.R".` I'm using android studio and I have the latest SDK packages.
gradle for the module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar')
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0"
}
```

Gradle file for the Project:

```
buildscript {
     repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        }
    }
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        } 
    }
```

these are my gradle files for the project

Comment: Please include your `build.gradle` files in your post. Possibly, you're using the same support library multiple times, e.g., once directly in your project and additionally via another library.

Comment: Try removing the `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0"` dependency.

Comment: than I get a tons of " Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'." errors

Comment: @dabbihall Post both your `build.gradle`s and everything in them.

Comment: are you sure your project is not not configured to depend on ***two*** compatibility libraries?

Comment: both of my gradle files are now in

Comment: Solved it, the problem was, for some reason, that the      ´    compileOptions     {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        } ´   

was in the wrong place

I simply moved it above the build types and voila

Comment: @dabbihall I posted an updated `build.gradle` as an answer for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move "`compileOptions`" outside of your "`defaultConfig`".

I also updated your "`buildToolsVersion`".

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    compileOptions { // <-- Moved this outside of your defaultConfig
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0' // <-- brings in support-v4
}
```